# Logic behind Pandas LOC selecting values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to learn and UNDERSTAND the logic behind pandas LOC and I can not come around with an explanation for the following issue.
If I want to slice the dataframe with LOC I can do it in the following way

```
dates=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

print(df.loc['20130102':'20130104',['A','B']])  (*)
```

All fine.
What I don't understand is that if in the second part of LOC I can entry a list of columns headers ['A','B'] why can't I do the same for the rows? 
i.e. the following would not work

```
print(df.loc[['20130102','20130104'],['A','B']])
```

What is the logic behind? I am giving LOC two row indexes, and two columns headers, but it would not work. For the columns part a list is fine, for the rows part it's not.
Moreover,
in the first part of the LOC (see *) the indexes of the rows can be accessed with ":" i.e. from index1 to index2 = 'index1':'index2' but I can not do the same in part 2 of the LOC function:
this would not work:

```
print(df.loc['20130102':'20130104',['A':'C']])
```

I would be glad to understand why those two showed lines of codes are not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need convert values of list to `datetime`s because `DatetimeIndex`, it means is necessary same types of values of list and values of index/columns of DataFrame, else `KeyError`:

```
print(df.loc[pd.to_datetime(['20130102','20130104']),['A','B']])
                   A         B
2013-01-02  0.719469  0.423106
2013-01-04  0.438572  0.059678
```

**Selecting by first and last value of index/columns**

Converting to `datetimes` is not necessary, because [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing).

For select by range remove only list `[]` for selecting columns:

```
print(df.loc['20130102':'20130104','A':'C'])
                   A         B         C
2013-01-02  0.719469  0.423106  0.980764
2013-01-03  0.480932  0.392118  0.343178
2013-01-04  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044
```

Similar solution for selecting of datetimes:

```
print(df.loc['2013-01-02':'2013-01-04','A':'C'])
                   A         B         C
2013-01-02  0.719469  0.423106  0.980764
2013-01-03  0.480932  0.392118  0.343178
2013-01-04  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044
```

Combinations:

```
#select betwen start/end datetime and only columns A,C
print(df.loc['20130102':'20130104',['A','C']])
                   A         C
2013-01-02  0.719469  0.980764
2013-01-03  0.480932  0.343178
2013-01-04  0.438572  0.398044

#select only 20130102, 20130104 index and columns between A and C
print(df.loc[pd.to_datetime(['20130102','20130104']),'A':'C'])
                   A         B         C
2013-01-02  0.719469  0.423106  0.980764
2013-01-04  0.438572  0.059678  0.398044
```

Comment: You mean it has something to do with the fact that the indexes are dates? I am going to try what happens if the index were for instance row1, row2, row3, i.e. pure text

Comment: @Berlines - Yes, it is important, because is used [`partial-string-indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) - so is not necessary converting both values to datetimes like `print(df.loc[pd.to_datetime('20130102'):pd.to_datetime('20130104'),'A':'C'])`

Comment: @Berlines - You are relly close, if want select by first and last value with `:` between is necessary remove list, so working `print(df.loc[['row1','row3'], 'A':'C'])`

Comment: If want select by lists, need `print(df.loc[['row1','row3'], ['A', 'C']])` - select only A, C columns

Answer (score 1):

This code explains the different ways to access data (slicing) with LOC in pandas:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4),index=['row1','row2','row3','row4','row5','row6'],columns=list('ABCD'))
         A         B         C         D
row1  0.972614  0.193116  0.448413  0.731300
row2  0.135391  0.783295  0.959058  0.107872
row3  0.966703  0.742793  0.852716  0.710681
row4  0.976819  0.920898  0.665329  0.078999
row5  0.418717  0.122677  0.716004  0.977522
row6  0.101422  0.641862  0.157751  0.888720
```

row_range  column_range:

```
df.loc['row1':'row3', 'A':'C']

            A         B         C
row1  0.972614  0.193116  0.448413
row2  0.135391  0.783295  0.959058
row3  0.966703  0.742793  0.852716
```

values_rows column_range:

```
df.loc[['row1','row3'], 'A':'C']
             A         B         C
row1  0.972614  0.193116  0.448413
row3  0.966703  0.742793  0.852716
```

row_range  column_values:

```
df.loc['row1':'row3', ['A','C']]
            A         C
row1  0.972614  0.448413
row2  0.135391  0.959058
row3  0.966703  0.852716
```

Single value:

```
df.loc['row1','A'])

0.972614309371533
```

conclusion: when using a range don't put it between [] 
But use the [] to include a list of values.